# Dafny GCD lemma Proof

Tags: proof, dafny, proof-of-correctness

I'd like to use dafny to prove the following lemma about GCD: For all k natural numbers, if k|a and k|b, then k|gcd(a,b). I have the following code so far:

```
// Euclid's algorithm for computing the greatest common divisor
function gcd(a: nat, b: nat): nat
    requires a > 0 && b > 0
{
    if a == b then a else 
    if b > a then gcd(a, b - a) else 
    gcd(a - b, b) 
}

predicate divides(a: nat, b:nat)
    requires a > 0
{
exists k: nat :: b == k * a
}

lemma dividesLemma(a: nat, b: nat)
//k|a && k|b ==> k|gcd(a,b)
requires a > 0 && b > 0
    ensures gcd(a,b) > 0
    ensures forall k: nat :: divides(a,k) && divides(b,k) ==> divides(gcd(a,b),k)
{
    if(a == b) {
        assert a * 1 == gcd(a,b);
        assert b * 1 == gcd(a,b);
    } else if b > a {
        if(divides(a, b)) {
            assert divides(a,a);
            assert divides(a,b);
            assert divides(a, gcd(a,b));
        } else {
            dividesLemma(a, b - a);
        }
    } else {
        if(divides(b, a)) {
            assert divides(b,b);
            assert divides(b,a);
            assert divides(b, gcd(a,b));
        } else {
            dividesLemma(a, a - b);
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to do the proof for this by hand. I would consider the prime factorization of a and b and say that gcd(a,b) was the combined prime factorization such that we take the minimal number of primes from each prime factorization. For instance if a = 9 and b = 15, the prime factorization of 9 = 3x3 and the prime factorization of 15 = 3x5, so the gcd(9,5) = 3 since that's the minimal combination of their prime factoizations. Using this fact it should be clear that if k|b and k|a, k must contain those minimal primes. How can I express this using dafny? Currently, I'm considering the base case if a=b and if a|b or b|a, but not sure how to incorporate the fact that it's possible for a and b to not share common primes in their prime factorizations.

Any help would be much appreciated for this!

Comment: Not answering because I don't know Dafny, but you don't need prime factorization for this -- it suffices to show by induction on d that both arguments of the recursive invocation at depth d are divisible by k.

Comment: Can you please outline the proof by induction? What would my base case be and how would I recurse until depth d? Could you please provide me with the proof you have in mind as an answer? @DavidEisenstat

Comment: If a = b, then k|a implies k|gcd(a, b) since a = gcd(a, b). Otherwise, we proceed by strong induction on max(a, b). The base case max(a, b) = 1 is trivial because a = b = 1. Inductively, if k|a and k|b, then letting c = min(a, b) and d = max(a, b), we do some algebra to show that k|c and k|d-c and max(c, d) < max(a, b), so applying the inductive hypothesis to the recursive call gcd(c, d) gives us k|gcd(a, b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in how `divides` is being called. I think
in ensures clauses you meant `divides(k, a)` instead of `divides(a, k)`
similarly for `divides(b, k)` and `divides(gcd(a, b), k)`.

One way to go about this after recursive call to `dividesLemma(a, b - a)` is
to use postcondition of method. Here we know forall `k` such that `k` divides `a` and `k` divides `b - a` implies `k` divides `gcd(a, b-a)`. Using this information we try to prove required postcondition (code or proof is straightforward to follow)

```
dividesLemma(a, b - a);
assert gcd(a, b) == gcd(a, b-a);
assert forall k : nat :: k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b-a) ==> divides(k, gcd(a, b));
forall k : nat | k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b) ensures divides(k, gcd(a, b)) {
    var m :| a == m * k;
    var n :| b == n * k;
    assert (b - a) == (n - m) * k;
    assume n >= m;
    assert divides(k, a);
    assert divides(k, b-a);
    // Implied from last assert forall
    assert divides(k, gcd(a, b)); 
}
```

Here I am assuming `n >= m` because `divides` requires `n-m` to be `nat`, which can proved separately.

Also second recursive call should be `dividesLemma(a - b, b)`.

```
function gcd(a: nat, b: nat): nat
  requires a > 0 && b > 0
{
  if a == b
    then a
  else if a < b
    then gcd(a, b-a)
  else gcd(a-b, b)
}

predicate divides(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires a > 0 && b > 0
{
  exists k: nat :: b == k * a
}

lemma helper(a: nat, b: nat, k : nat)
  requires a > 0 && b > 0 && k > 0
  requires divides(k, a) && divides(k, b)
  requires b >= a
  ensures exists m, n :: a == m * k && b == n * k && m <= n;
{ }
    
lemma dividesLemma(a: nat, b: nat)
  decreases a + b
  requires a > 0 && b > 0
  ensures gcd(a, b) > 0
  ensures forall k: nat :: k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b) ==> divides(k, gcd(a, b))
{
  if (a == b){
  }
  else if (b > a){
    dividesLemma(a, b - a);
    assert gcd(a, b) == gcd(a, b-a);
    assert forall k : nat :: k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b-a) ==> divides(k, gcd(a, b));
    forall k : nat | k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b) ensures divides(k, gcd(a, b)) {
      helper(a, b, k);
      var m, n :| a == m * k && b == n * k && m <= n;
      assert b - a == (n - m) * k;
      assert divides(k, b-a);
    }
  }
  else {
    dividesLemma(a - b, b);
    assert gcd(a, b) == gcd(a - b, b);
    assert forall k : nat :: k > 0 && divides(k, a-b) && divides(k, b) ==> divides(k, gcd(a, b));
    forall k : nat | k > 0 && divides(k, a) && divides(k, b) ensures divides(k, gcd(a, b)) {
      helper(b, a, k);
      var m, n :| b == m * k && a == n * k && m <= n;
      assert a - b == (n - m) * k;
      assert divides(k, a-b);
    }
  }
}
```